# ASP button not showing on iframe

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, aspbutton

I am developing an asp.net web application.
I have used Iframe control. Whenever I add a button to it.It is not shown on Iframe.
Please look at the following code.

```
<iframe style="border: none" name="myIframe" id="myIframe" runat="server" height="100%" width="100%" >
                           <asp:Button runat="server" Width="20" Height="20" />
                        </iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any particular reason for using iframe? Use a div or a panel instead?

Comment: I want to update a section of web page not the whole page.

Comment: Use Update panels or jquery